# Register function that will be called before system call

Tags: operating-system, pthreads, fork, system-calls

How can we register function such that it will be called before executing system call.
For example, `pthread_atfork()` registers functions that will be called before and after `fork()`.

Below is the example on Linux system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_atfork.html

void prepare_function() {
    printf("%d : In Prepare Function\n", getpid());
}

void parent_fuction() {
    printf("%d : In Parent Function\n", getpid());
}

void child_function() {
    printf("%d : In Child Function\n", getpid());
}

int main() {
    pthread_atfork(prepare_function, parent_fuction, child_function);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        //sleep(1);
        printf("%d : In Child\n", getpid());
        return 0;
    }

    //sleep(1);
    printf("%d : In Parent\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

I'm curious about how this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual goal here?

Fork has hooks because the state of the child with presence of threads in undefined. So by hooking yourself up you can ensure whatever mechanisms you want to use remain operational (for instance, if the fork happened after one of your threads takes a lock, the lock will remain taken within the child - what now?).

In general there is no mechanism which provides hooks for all syscalls.

For the most part syscalls are wrapped in glibc so there are few entry points which actually call the kernel. Someone bored enough could hack this up by e.g. inserting a jump in generated code to which would land the execution in their routine. But such a routine would have to have its own way of calling syscalls or a hack.

But wait, any piece of code is free to call a syscall without the use of such wrappers and such code could be dynamically generated, so you can't binary patch it prior to execution.

You can trace syscall entry/exit with ptrace, but you need a separate process for that.